# How do we convert the string in to int array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Below program explains conversion of String to byte array

```
class Simple {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String st = "Hello World";
        byte[] b = st.bytes();
    }
}
```

Can anyone let me know is there any predefined method in string, which can convert the string to int array like we have done in the above program to byte array?

Comment: No, there is no predefined method in class `String` to do that. See the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Why exactly do you need this? If you can explain that, we can help you find a good solution to the actual problem that you're trying to solve.

Comment: do you want to convert Hello World into int.?

Comment: You can call `String.toCharArray()` which returns indeed a `char[]` but you can cast any value stored within to an `int` without any trouble.

Comment: So is there any way we can convert the string to int array?

Comment: You can not do that. You can convert string into char array. If you have some other requirements then be specific.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8 you can use `chars()`

```
String st = "Hello World";
int[] array = st.chars().toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Outputs

```
[72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

---

Unfortunately there are other solutions as mention in comment :

#### Solution 2 by [@TyeolRik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7105963)

If you want an array of bytes you can just use :

```
byte[] array = st.getBytes();
```

#### Solution 3 by [@saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4910279)

You can use [CharSequence.html#codePoints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) like this :

```
int[] array = st.codePoints().toArray();
```

Comment: `int[] ints = "Hello World".chars().toArray();` would be enough. Why `long`?

Comment: ```byte[] b = st.getBytes();``` why line 2 is too long?

Comment: and also, result is same.

Comment: You can use `.codePoints().toArray()`, if you want to gather surrogate pair into single integer.

Comment: thank you @saka1029 I add your solution to my answer.

Comment: @TyeolRik I add your solution in my answer hope it can help other in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "12 41 21 19 15 10";
// The string you want to be an integer array.
String[] integerStrings = test.split(" ");
// Splits each spaced integer into a String array.
int[] integers = new int[integerStrings.length];
// Creates the integer array.
for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
    integers[i] = Integer.parseInt(integerStrings[i]);
    //Parses the integer for each string.
}
```

This can also be the way to convert String to a Integer ! It would be interesting to know other ways ! Instead of space you can use comma (,) or any other as delimiter !